# Python get output of subprocess that does not terminate

Tags: python, subprocess

I'd like to start a subprocess, wait 10 seconds and get its output. This subprocess won't terminate by itself (it will run forever by design) so I need to use a timeout.
The following code starts a subprocess and raise a timeout after 10 seconds:

```
import subprocess

try:
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.wait(timeout=10)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    print('Timeout reached')
```

However, I am not sure how to read the output of the process generated during these 10 seconds:

```
print(process.stderr)
<_io.BufferedReader name=11>
print(process.stdout)
<_io.BufferedReader name=8>
```

EDIT: `process.stderr.read()` and `process.stdout.read()` seem to hang forever. This may be because the subprocess has been terminated after the timeout.

Comment: One place to start figuring out what to do next is the [documentation for the io module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html). In particular, you need to look at the `BufferedReader` class and figure out how to use it.

Comment: I think they may be empty. See above.